# Why does the empty set not get a relation in a cartesian product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, direct-product

As far as I understand, when $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$, then $A \times B =\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$.
But $\emptyset \in A$ and $\emptyset \in B$. Are any of these valid? If not, why not?

a. $(\emptyset, 1) \in A \times B$

b. $(1, \emptyset) \in A \times B$

c. $(\emptyset, \emptyset) \in A \times B$

d. $\emptyset \in A \times B$

Comment: N.B.: cross product is an operation on 3D vectors completely unrelated to the question. What you have here is usually called the Cartesian product or just product.

Comment: Second note: neither of $\varnothing \in A$ and $\varnothing \in B$ is true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, $\emptyset$ is not element of $A$ (or of $B$). The set $\emptyset$ is a *subset* of $A$ (and of any other set), but that's irrelevant for your question.

Comment: Thanks for pinpointing my misunderstanding. It makes sense now.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree. Thanks. I have updated the accepted answer.